# How to embed flash files in iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, flash

I have some flash files and i need to integrate those files in iPad app. i searched lot but everyone's answer is

**- iOS will not support flash.**

**- even if you integrate flash files app store will not accept.**

But my app is not for app store this is an enterprise app. Instead of integrating flash files we can do all the animation in our objective-c itself. But client is demanding to integrate flash files in iPad app. Is there any alternate solution. Please guide me.

Comment: iOS doesn't support flash.  You will have to consider alternatives.

Comment: thank for your comments what would be alternate solution

Comment: Html5 would be an alternative if you aren't willing to do your own animations using the framework. A product named Smokescreen is available and it reads your flash file and supposedly converts it to Html5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can run Flash apps on iOS, you just have to build them using [AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html):

> Adobe AIR is a cross-platform runtime that enables you to use your
>   existing Flash/ActionScript or HTML/JavaScript development skills and
>   tools to build and deploy applications, games, and videos outside the
>   browser and on mobile devices.

[Here is the specific resources page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air_for_ios.html) on how to build Flash ActionScript 3 apps targeting any iOS device.

The beauty of AIR is that if the code of your app is well organized, you can reuse most of it for any build being it for Android, iOS, Blackberry, or even a desktop app (windows and macosx) or the web.

Answer (score 1):

***Hybrid way:***

Flash to html5 conversion then open HTML document using webview

- **Google swiffy:**

Swf to HTML 5

*Note:*

maximum of 1 mb only be converted at present

*Link:*

[click here](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/)

- **Adobe wallaby:**

Fla to HTML 5

*Note:*

At present cs5 only supported.the lower versions have to be resaved in cs5 to convert.

*Link:*

[click here](http://adobe-wallaby.en.malavida.com/)

***Native way:***

- **Adobe air:**

One could run actioscript flash content directly in ios devices.

*Note:*

At present you could make stand alone ios apps only you can't integrate with existing app.

*Link:*

[click here](http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2012/12/ios-apps-flash-cs6.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a detour only, but you could install the [Photon](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/photon-flash-video-player/id430200224?mt=8) browser and call it from your app.