# playing flash files in iphone

Tags: iphone, flash

we have a client application that plays flash files (.swf). This works on all other mobiles except iphone as Apple doesn't support Flash. Is there any workaround to play these flash files in iphone using HTML5 or any other tweaking? Since there aren't any answers to this question recently, I am submiting this question.

Comment: are you interested in playing the animation or the AS2/AS3 code as well? Is your client app made with AIR or some other technology?

Comment: my client app is developed using jquery, jquery mobile. Leaving aside my client app, say I have a .swf file and I want to play it on iphone, how can I do this?

Comment: The bad news are - you can't. You could if the client app was an AIR application and if you want to use HTML generated content with JS in it you could use AIR's native WEB View support. But that's not a fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to display a Flash file (SWF) in the iPhone browser.

If you have access to the source of the Flash files in the application, it may be possible to export them as HTML5 from the Flash builder. There's no way to do this conversion just from the SWFs, though.

As an aside: your application won't work on many newer smartphones either - under Android, Adobe has dropped support for the Flash plugin on current versions of the OS, and it's not supported at all on current versions of Windows Mobile or Blackberry OS. Sites which depend on Flash content are effectively unusable on mobile at this point.

Comment: how to export them as HTML5 from the Flash builder? after export, how to use that to play the files in iphone?

Answer (score 0):

- **using external browser:**

  There is a browser called **photon** which plays *flash videos and games* on ios devices without any need to jailbreak open this browser with the web url using custom app url scheme
- **using html5 conversion tools:**

  Use *google swiffy* or  *Adobe wallaby* and open the HTML page using uiwebview
- **native app**

  Using *Adobe air sdk* you could play local flash videos natively

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167057/730807) to see detailed answer that compares these approaches and too see main links to these approaches