# Playing flash file on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, flash

I have small flash games, for now I want to create App which will pay the existing flash. I know Apple is not supporting flash, but is there any way to run flash in iPhone/iPad App?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456454/playing-flash-files-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that iOS doesn't support Flash and that there is not any way to get flash running on iOS, this technology is getting depreciated and old-fashion.
I know that if you jailbreak your iOS device there was possibilities to run flash but I guess you want to share your games so this is not the right way to proceed.

A good way could be to translate your flash games to another compatible language for iOS like HTML5 (and with using something like Phonegap you could share it on multiple mobile platforms):

- http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-quickly-convert-flash-games-into-mobile-apps/
  or
- https://pixelplant.com/

I've never tried those solutions so they are maybe not the best one, I advise you to look for the best way to port your flash games to make it compatible with iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 0):

As i know if you have jailbreaked your iPhone you can give a try to find some package like Frash(not flash here) from Cydia. but frash package can be used only for iphone iOS 3.2,3.2.1, 4.0, 4.0.1.